Directory import not supported
Before now I was using CommonJS and module-alias but I want to move over to ES modules and switch to the natively supported import mappings, so I refactored to this in my package.json:
{
   "imports": {
      "#http/*": "./http/",
      "#cloud/*": "./cloud/",
      "#constants": "./constants"
    } 
}

However when I do this in my server.js:
import APIClient from '#http/apiClient';

I get the following error:

Directory import /Users/me/sampleApp/http/ is not supported

This was working perfectly fine with module-alias what am I doing wrong now?

try this, Instead of using # use @, if you want relative import

@AminTaghikhani the native import mapping implementation doesn't support the use of @. I don't know why they settled for # instead of the @ everyone is used to.

With these subpath patterns, you need to specify the wildcard on both sides, and the extension too:
{
  "imports": {
    "#http/*": "./http/*",
    "#cloud/*": "./cloud/*",
    "#constants": "./constants.js"
  } 
}

import APIClient from '#http/apiClient.js';


* maps expose nested subpaths as it is a string replacement syntax only.
All instances of * on the right hand side will then be replaced with this value, including if it contains any / separators.

